# Finding pairs of symbols in the end of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a program that returns ...

- -1 for an empty string
- 0 for a single-character string
- next-to-last index if the final two characters match
- last index if they are different

For instance:

```
    "tara" => 3
    "baa" => 1
    "adjsk" => 4
    "sthkk"=> 3
    "a" => 0
```

It seems that I'm returning index of last character wrongly:

```
def ends_with_pair(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            return s.index(s[i])
        return s.index(s[-1])
```

Also, is there a way to make it more compact?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code produces no output, and you haven't tested all the cases you describe.

Comment: What would you expect your program to return for `abbas`?

Comment: If you are looking for compact, then `len(s)-1 if len(s)<2 else len(s)-1-(s[-1]==s[-2])` will do what you want, but I don't recommend writing _that_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is far too complex.  The problem involves *only* the final two characters; there's no need to loop through the string.

1. Check the string length; if it's 0, return -1.  If it's 1, return 0.
2. Check the last two characters against each other `s[-1] == s[-2]`.  If they're equal, return len(s)-2; else return len(s)-1.

I trust you can turn that into code.

Comment: Missing one case: single-character strings.

Comment: Good grab; thanks.  Fixed now.